# WMS/WFS connection in QGIS failed

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, wfs

I have Geoserver 2.21.4, running on Ubuntu 22.4.
I created few WMS and WFS maps, and I was able to add them into Civil 3D and Map 3D.

Only in QGIS 3.22 and 3.28 I can't add the servers. It's always failig and asks me every few seconds for password.

Please help.

Thanks and Regards
Levon

Created WFS and WFS services and expecting to connect in QGIS.
But as Result got connected only in Autodesk Civil 3D

Comment: how did  you add them to QGIS? did you provide a username? I assume you haven't set up any security?

Comment: Actually I have set up the security. Otherwise it wouldn't work in Autodesk environment.

Comment: Then you need to save the password in the WFS/wms connection